# Do I have to reconfigure anything when upgrading my MacBooks RAM?

Tags: macos, memory, macbook

I have just upgraded my 2009 MacBook RAM from 2GB to 8GB.

Everything works just fine whilst I am using it, things seem much snappier in general most of the time. The main problem occurs when I restart after hibernating. It will consistently crash and reboot the Mac. Also some high intensity tasks seems to now take ridiculous amounts of CPU. Compiling in XCode at times is much slower..

I spend a couple of days running MemTest, and no problems were found with the memory, so as far as I can tell I haven't been sold broken goods. It's got me thinking that perhaps something needs to be configured somewhere.

It's got me thinking that perhaps the increased RAM now means it has to create a bigger swap file and isn't able to.. pure speculation..

Any ideas?

Comment: Normally you should be fine without doing anything. Any chance you bought "incompatible" RAM? (Which one did you buy?)

Comment: I suppose anything is possible. This is what I bought [Kingston 8GB 2x4GB DDR3 RAM PC3 8500 1066MHz 204 Pin SODIMM](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B001PS9UKW/ref=pe_385721_37038051_pe_217191_31005151_M3T1_dp_1)

Comment: I would have thought that if it was incompatible nothing would really work, or it would crash more during use rather than just at one specific point.

Comment: You won't have to configure anything at all. Any problems will either be that the RAM is incompatible or incorrectly installed or faulty.

Comment: I had major problems with upgrading ram.  From my experience make VERY sure that the ram is mac compatible.   Not just looking at the raw specs.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your mac if it supports 4gb and 1066MHz each slot
- I got same problem when i upgraded my mac the problem was the memory i bought was untraceable no serial number.

Comment: If it didn't wouldn't memtest have picked up a problem?

Comment: Not really tried it as well but it did not detect anything for me. anyway i got kernel problems when i upgraded so i just left one memory i bought and inserted the old one it worked great first time i started after upgraded my ram it worked but second time it showed me kernel dump both mac and linux